# If $Z=X$ on $A$ and $Z=Y$ on $A^c$ then $Z$ is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random random variables and let $A \in \mathcal{B}$. Prove that the function $Z$ defined by
>   $$Z(\omega)=\begin{cases} 
>       X(\omega),& \text{ if } \omega \in A  \\
>       Y(\omega),& \text{ if } \omega \in A^{c}
>    \end{cases}$$
>   is a random variable

**Proof so far:**
$$Z^{-1}((-\infty,a])=\{\omega:Z(\omega)\geq a\}=\{\omega: Z(\omega)\geq a,  \omega \in A\}\cup\{\omega: Z(\omega)\leq a,  \omega \in A^{c}\}=Y^{-1}[a,\infty) \cup X^{-1}([a,\infty))$$
So $Z$ is measurable

Comment: Every single equality is wrong, please take your time and rework the details of your proof.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning once again, since the accepted answer wrongly claims that the proof in the question is correct modulo some small typos, that the identity $$Z^{-1}((-\infty,a])=Y^{-1}[a,\infty) \cup X^{-1}([a,\infty))$$ is actually squarely wrong, as would be the identity $$Z^{-1}([a,\infty))=Y^{-1}([a,\infty)) \cup X^{-1}([a,\infty))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X, Y$ be random variables in $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mathbb P)$.

If $A \in \mathcal B$, then $1_A$ and $1_{A^C}$ are random variables.

Note that

$$Z = X1_A + Y1_{A^C}$$

Since sums or products of random variables in $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mathbb P)$ are random variables in $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mathbb P)$, $Z$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal B, \mathbb P)$.

---

As for your proof, I think you should say:

1. $\forall a \in \mathbb R$
2. have $Z \ge a$ instead of $Z \le a$
3. $Z$ is $\mathcal B$-measurable

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be a borel set then 
$$Z^{-1}(B)=[Z^{-1}(B)\cap A] \cup [Z^{-1}(B)\cap A^{c}]=[X^{-1}(B)\cap A] \cup [Y^{-1}(B)\cap A^{c}] \\ 
= X^{-1}(B) \cup Y^{-1}(B)$$
By the property of $\sigma$ field we see that $Z$ is a random variable

Comment: @Dominik  check out my solution

Comment: Josh, I don't think Dominik was notified because he didn't edit or comment on this post. Looks okay. Pretty much the same as the one you gave in OP (by uniqueness lemma) I guess. I think you can omit the A's at the end but should replace 1 of the X's with a Y